# Vcpkg opencv and opencv4 different

Tags: c++, opencv, vcpkg

I wanna install opencv with the [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg). But I as I search for opencv with :

```
vcpkg search opencv
```

and see this output

```
opencv                   4.8.0            Computer vision library
opencv[ade]                               graph api
opencv[contrib]                           opencv_contrib module
opencv[cuda]                              CUDA support for opencv
opencv[cudnn]                             cuDNN support for opencv
opencv[dc1394]                            Dc1394 support for opencv
opencv[default-features]                  Platform-dependent default features
opencv[dnn]                               Enable dnn module
opencv[dnn-cuda]                          Build dnn module with CUDA support
opencv[eigen]                             Eigen support for opencv
opencv[ffmpeg]                            ffmpeg support for opencv
opencv[freetype]                          freetype support for opencv
opencv[gdcm]                              GDCM support for opencv
opencv[gstreamer]                         gstreamer support for opencv
opencv[gtk]                               GTK support for opencv
opencv[halide]                            Halide support for opencv
opencv[ipp]                               Enable Intel Integrated Performance Primitives
opencv[jasper]                            JPEG 2000 support for opencv
opencv[jpeg]                              JPEG support for opencv
opencv[lapack]                            LAPACK support for opencv
opencv[nonfree]                           opencv nonfree module
opencv[openexr]                           OpenEXR support for opencv
opencv[opengl]                            opengl support for opencv
opencv[openmp]                            Enable openmp support for opencv
opencv[ovis]                              opencv_ovis module
opencv[png]                               PNG support for opencv
opencv[python]                            Python wrapper support for opencv
opencv[qt]                                Qt GUI support for opencv
opencv[quirc]                             Enable QR code module
opencv[sfm]                               opencv_sfm module
opencv[tbb]                               Enable Intel Threading Building Blocks
opencv[tiff]                              TIFF support for opencv
opencv[vtk]                               vtk support for opencv
opencv[webp]                              WebP support for opencv
opencv[world]                             Compile to a single package support for opencv
opencv2                  2.4.13.7#19      Open Source Computer Vision Library
opencv2[cuda]                             CUDA support for opencv
opencv2[dc1394]                           Dc1394 support for opencv
opencv2[default-features]                 Platform-dependent default features
opencv2[eigen]                            Eigen support for opencv
opencv2[ffmpeg]                           ffmpeg support for opencv
opencv2[gtk]                              GTK support for opencv
opencv2[jasper]                           JPEG 2000 support for opencv
opencv2[jpeg]                             JPEG support for opencv
opencv2[openexr]                          OpenEXR support for opencv
opencv2[opengl]                           opengl support for opencv
opencv2[png]                              PNG support for opencv
opencv2[python]                           Python wrapper support for opencv
opencv2[qt]                               Qt GUI support for opencv
opencv2[tiff]                             TIFF support for opencv
opencv2[world]                            Compile to a single package support for opencv
opencv3                  3.4.18#12        Open Source Computer Vision Library
opencv3[contrib]                          opencv_contrib module
opencv3[cuda]                             CUDA support for opencv
opencv3[dc1394]                           Dc1394 support for opencv
opencv3[default-features]                 Platform-dependent default features
opencv3[dnn]                              Enable dnn module
opencv3[eigen]                            Eigen support for opencv
opencv3[ffmpeg]                           ffmpeg support for opencv
opencv3[flann]                            opencv_flann module
opencv3[freetype]                         Freetype support for opencv
opencv3[gdcm]                             GDCM support for opencv
opencv3[gstreamer]                        gstreamer support for opencv
opencv3[gtk]                              GTK support for opencv
opencv3[halide]                           Halide support for opencv
opencv3[ipp]                              Enable Intel Integrated Performance Primitives
opencv3[jasper]                           JPEG 2000 support for opencv
opencv3[jpeg]                             JPEG support for opencv
opencv3[lapack]                           LAPACK support for opencv
opencv3[nonfree]                          allow nonfree and unredistributable libraries
opencv3[openexr]                          OpenEXR support for opencv
opencv3[opengl]                           opengl support for opencv
opencv3[openmp]                           Enable openmp support for opencv
opencv3[ovis]                             opencv_ovis module
opencv3[png]                              PNG support for opencv
opencv3[python]                           Python wrapper support for opencv
opencv3[qt]                               Qt GUI support for opencv
opencv3[quirc]                            Enable QR code module
opencv3[sfm]                              opencv_sfm module
opencv3[tbb]                              Enable Intel Threading Building Blocks
opencv3[tiff]                             TIFF support for opencv
opencv3[vtk]                              vtk support for opencv
opencv3[webp]                             WebP support for opencv
opencv3[world]                            Compile to a single package support for opencv
opencv4                  4.8.0#12         computer vision library
opencv4[ade]                              graph api
opencv4[contrib]                          opencv_contrib module
opencv4[cuda]                             CUDA support for opencv
opencv4[cudnn]                            cuDNN support for opencv
opencv4[dc1394]                           Dc1394 support for opencv
opencv4[default-features]                 Platform-dependent default features
opencv4[dnn]                              Enable dnn module
opencv4[dnn-cuda]                         Build dnn module with CUDA support
opencv4[eigen]                            Eigen support for opencv
opencv4[ffmpeg]                           ffmpeg support for opencv
opencv4[freetype]                         Freetype support for opencv
opencv4[gdcm]                             GDCM support for opencv
opencv4[gstreamer]                        gstreamer support for opencv
opencv4[gtk]                              GTK support for opencv
opencv4[halide]                           Halide support for opencv
opencv4[ipp]                              Enable Intel Integrated Performance Primitives
opencv4[jasper]                           JPEG 2000 support for opencv (deprecated)
opencv4[jpeg]                             JPEG support for opencv
opencv4[lapack]                           LAPACK support for opencv
opencv4[nonfree]                          allow nonfree and unredistributable libraries
opencv4[openexr]                          OpenEXR support for opencv
opencv4[opengl]                           opengl support for opencv
opencv4[openjpeg]                         JPEG 2000 support for opencv
opencv4[openmp]                           Enable openmp support for opencv
opencv4[openvino]                         OpenVINO support for OpenCV DNN
opencv4[ovis]                             opencv_ovis module
opencv4[png]                              PNG support for opencv
opencv4[python]                           Python wrapper support for opencv
opencv4[qt]                               Qt GUI support for opencv
opencv4[quirc]                            Enable QR code module
opencv4[sfm]                              opencv_sfm module
opencv4[tbb]                              Enable Intel Threading Building Blocks
opencv4[tiff]                             TIFF support for opencv
opencv4[vtk]                              vtk support for opencv
opencv4[webp]                             WebP support for opencv
opencv4[world]                            Compile to a single package support for opencv
```

It's pretty clear for me that opencv2, opencv3 and opencv4 is different version of opencv, but the first opencv still mark with 4.8.0, the same as opencv4. So, what the different between these 2? what should I choose ? And what the #12 after 4.8.0 mean?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pulls?q=opencv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, what the different between these 2? what should I choose ?

`opencv` is a port that installs latest major version of OpenCV. When you run `vcpkg install opencv` it will install `opencv` (empty port) and `opencv4`. It doesn't really matter what you choose except that you would need to change `opencv4` to `opencv5` if it ever gets released.

> And what the #12 after 4.8.0 mean?

It means "`opencv` version 4.8.0, port revision 12".
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcpkg/users/versioning#port-version